# 301 redirect regex for file paths to uploads directory

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am moving a website to wordpress and the site has hundreds of files available for download. The current file path may have a number of subfolders before the name of the file. Below are some examples of how a url may look.

```
"http://www.example.com/uploads/folder/subfolder/anothersubfolder/file.pdf"

"http://www.example.com/uploads/folder/file.pdf"

  "http://www.example.com/uploads/folder/subfolder/anothersubfolder/anothersubfolder/file.doc"
```

I want to create a 301 redirect to handle any requests for these files and send them to the new url which would be

```
"http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/folder/subfolder"
```

I'm keeping the sub-folders the same in the uploads folder, so really I need a regex for pointing anything that goes to

```
"http://www.example.com/uploads/"
```

and point it to

```
"http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/"
```

### Update

My current .htaccess file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried adding the answer from anubhava within the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block but I think there is an issue with the `RewriteBase /` from wordpress and me trying to add `RewriteBase /uploads/`. How can I have a rewrite condition for the /uploads directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^uploads(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I ran into a problem with wordpress htaccess already having a RewriteBase so I've updated my question.

Comment: Actually my suggested htaccess needs to go in the htaccess file in uploads directory not in the root htaccess file.

Comment: I believe `/uploads/` is a real directory. In case it isn't let me know.

Comment: it would have been on the old website but it won't exist anymore.

Comment: OK try updated rule. I have provided your full .htaccess for `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`